# Cc socket programming select()'s first argument

Tags: c++, sockets, select

I have been trying to do some network programming in Linux but I seem to be stuck again. I don't seem to get the first argument of the select() function.  It should be the last made socket `filedescriptor + 1` as far as I know.  Mostly the highest `filedescriptor` contains the number 6. When I add the `filedescriptor` to the `fd_set` it suddenly changes to 64--probably because it changes to `fd_bytes` (correct me if I'm wrong). So, 6+1 does not seem to make it for the select statement because it keeps blocking, but not if I get the `fd_bytes` from the `fd_set`. I am very confused about all of this and would like to have some advice on the subject or if someone had it, a good tutorial for sigio that could make things easier.

**Server.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

using namespace std;

void error(char *msg,int socket)
{
    perror(msg);
    close(socket);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, n;
    socklen_t clilen;
    fd_set readfds;
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
/*
 * Sockfd, newsockfd contain values returned by the socket
 * portno stores the port number on which the server accepts connections
 * clilen stores the size of the address of the client
 * n contains the amount of character written of read
 */
    char buffer[256];
    /* buffer contains the characters read from the socket*/

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    /* 
     * sockaddr_in contains an internet address
     * serv_addr contains the servers address
     * cli addr contains the clients address
     */
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR no port provided");
       exit(1);
    }
    /*
     * error if no argument
     */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    int opt = 1;
    ioctl(sockfd, FIONBIO, &opt);

    if(sockfd < 0){
        error("ERROR opening socket", sockfd);
    }    
    /*
     * socket() creates a new socket
     * argument 1 contains the address domain
     * argument 2 contains the socket type
     * argument 3 contains the protocol should be 0
     * socket() returns a reference for itself
     */
    bzero((char*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    /* empty the serv_addr variable*/
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);
    /*converts the port argument from string  to int*/
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    /*set the code for the address family*/
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    /*htons converts the portno to network bytes and gives it to the server address*/
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    /*set the server ip to the ip of the running machine*/
    if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR on binding", sockfd);
    /*
     * bind() binds a socket to an address, in this case the
     * addess of the current host
     */
    listen(sockfd,5);
    /*the listen system call allows the process to listen on the socket for 
    connections*/
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    do{
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    }while(newsockfd < 0);
    /*
     * accept() lets the system wait until a client connects to the server
     */
    FD_SET(newsockfd,&readfds);
    int sockcount = pselect(readfds.fds_bits[0] + 1,&readfds,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
    if(n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket", sockfd);
    printf("Here is the message: %s", buffer);
    /*
     * bzero empties the buffer
     * read obviously reads data from the new socket descriptor
     */
    n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
    if(n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket", sockfd);

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Some (or all) code might not make sense but that's mainly because I'm just testing how the code behaves and after that make it multi threaded. The code above works more of less: it can be tested with telnet or with client from the tutorial located here http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm.

Comment: Read these two links. [world of select](http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html) and [select_tut (2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select_tut)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seed anyone do `readfds.fds_bits[0] + 1` before. For your case, you could just use `newsockfd + 1` in `pselect()`.

Comment: it works, thanks, dont know why it didnt work the first time because i tryed that before but in that time it kept blocking.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for pselect, it will block if you don't supply the timespec argument, which is what's happening in your code. Regardless of this, your call to pselect is really serving no purpose because a) you don't make any decision based on result of the call to pselect and b) you call recv immediately afterwards which is a blocking call.

Comment: as i wrote most of the code does not realy make sence because i just want to know what to code realy does before i split things up and make sure i can handle multiple connections at a time and make read and write possible at the same time